# Spring Boot MVC in Azure Web App Service logging is not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-mvc, logback

We are deploying a Spring MVC application using Spring Boot, to Azure Web App Service.  We have the application deployed, and can hit the end points, but are unable to see logging output.  Logging is implemented with a logback.xml file and the logging levels are set in the application.properties file.

Note that logging works perfectly when deploying the application to Tomcat on a VM.  The logging output, when logged to stdout, is accessible in the catalina.out file.  But, when the application is pushed to Azure Web App Services, no logging output is accessible from the catalina.log file, nor anywhere else.

Unfortunately, the documentation for deploying Spring Boot apps to azure can be summed up as 'scant to none', but we need to accomplish this for our customer.  The documentation that is there, regarding logging for java, seems to want you to use [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-java-trace-logs).  Unfortunately, this is another service that costs money.  There has to be a way to view standard logs from a java app in Azure Web App Services.

Is there anyone out there who has any experience with this?  Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the logging level within the application.properties file within Spring Boot.

```
logging.level=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
```

Then within the web.config file set where the log whould be stored, i.e.

```
-Dlogging.file=&quot;%HOME%\LogFiles\boot.log&quot;
```

Then on the Console tab of the web application within Microsoft Azure you can specify that you would like to tail the log.

```
tail D:\home\LogFiles\boot.log
```

Comment: My Spring boot app is running but can't see the log. Also I don't have web.config in my directory.